# How to access my .ssh folder for Transmit or Cyberduck?

Tags: mac, ssh, macos, ftp

I"m trying to connect to my linux server which uses public key authentication. By default, the .ssh folder is hidden on my mac (which I can access via the terminal). However, when I try to setup a connection using either Cyberduck or Transmit, the Finder popup that opens does not show the .ssh folder.

How do I select the key ?

One alternative would be to copy the key to a directory outside the .ssh folder. But i'd definitely like to hear other solutions. How are you doing it ?

Comment: Transmit will honor your .ssh/config, and if you have a .ssh/id_rsa, it'll use that automatically.  Just connect like you normally would, but leave the password blank.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In the find file window, press Command-Shift-G.  It'll ask you what folder to navigate to.  Enter `~/.ssh` and press return.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell Transmit or Cyberduck to show your hidden folders. The `.` in the folder name is part of why it is hidden.

In Transmit, there should be a menu option in `View` -> `Show Invisible Files`. Cyberduck may have a similar menu option in the View menu, but it may say `Show Hidden Files`.

This will let you see it in the application. If you need to see it in an Open file dialog, press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>` while the open dialog window is open. This will drop down a "Go to the folder" screen. Type in the hidden folder path you wish to navigate to and that folder will now display in the open dialog window.

Comment: The question was specifically talking about finding the SSH key when configuring a connection in the FTP program, not how to see hidden files/folders in the windows to transfer between the remote and local computers. The end of your answer at least addresses that, but the start was going down the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Terminal window on your MAC (by default you will be in Home dir):

Type :

```
$ ls -la
```

This will list all the files & folder including hidden folders.

Comment: The question was specifically talking about finding the SSH key when configuring a connection in the FTP program, not how to see hidden files/folders in the Terminal window.