# How to get to .ssh path on macOS?

Tags: macos, ssh

I have tried the following steps from [How to access my .ssh folder for Transmit or Cyberduck?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/84733/37797):

> In the find file window, press Command-Shift-G. It'll ask you what folder to navigate to. Enter "~/.ssh" and press return.

… but I did not get any reply. The screen remains the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you quote the tilde it will loose its special meaning. Just type `~/.ssh`

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create the folder first. For this, open Terminal and run

```
mkdir ~/.ssh; chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Also, when entering `~/.ssh` in the dialog shown after pressing <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd> it's important to enter the string without the `""`:

[image]

Comment: Super proper answer. I forgot about the permissions aspect once and that is key for proper functioning. Be sure you check those if you backup and restore this directory and your backup method doesn’t preserve permissions.